# Encryption between laravel and flutter

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, encryption

So I have made an encryption middleware in laravel that encrypts data using the following code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return response()->json(encrypt($response->content()),$response->status());
    }
```

I ran the command

```
php artisan:generate key
```

So now I'm trying to decrypt this data from flutter I tried using encrypt package in flutter but still no luck in making it work.

I feel the problem is the following:

1- The key used in encryption ni laravel is APP_KEY right it is in the format `base64:random string` this should be my key without base64?

2- Flutter encryption package needs IV I keep trying to set it from the key but still failing would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Also, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933327/flutter-dart-aes-256-cbc-decrypting-from-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 2):

I have never done this between laravel and dart, but i have between two laravel apps.

```
    // bits stolen from the laravel EncryptionServiceProvider.php
    if (Str::startsWith($key = env('OTHER_APPS_API_APP_KEY'), 'base64:')) {
        $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
    }
    $encrypter = new Encrypter($key, config('app.cipher')); // probably AES-256-CBC

    // decrypt the data
    $encrypter->decrypt($theDataToDecrypt);
```

If you can find a library in dart that supports the same ciper you shoud be able to do the same

Comment: Thanksss alot you guided me to the right links I ended viewing the code of laravel to decrypt and mapped it to flutter