# Flutter / Dart AES-256-CBC encrypting a string in Dart and PHP

Tags: php, flutter, dart, encryption

Thanks to Topaco's answer to this question ([Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933327/flutter-dart-aes-256-cbc-decrypting-from-encryption-in-php)), I was able to decrypt an X string. But I can't get the same X string by encrypting the decryption result

I used this function to decrypt this string ("Hello World"), encrypted in PHP:

ZFNkckFEL2R5cW5ycTJpbWs0Ky9xQT09

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as EncryptPack;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart' as CryptoPack;
import 'dart:convert' as ConvertPack;

 String extractPayload(String payload) {
      String strPwd = "6P8yHVfeZ5JKaXQ6AyaBge";
      String strIv = 'cHaa5y7pQF5uqA2N';
      var iv = CryptoPack.sha256
          .convert(ConvertPack.utf8.encode(strIv))
          .toString()
          .substring(0, 16); // Consider the first 16 bytes of all 64 bytes
      var key = CryptoPack.sha256
          .convert(ConvertPack.utf8.encode(strPwd))
          .toString()
          .substring(0, 32); // Consider the first 32 bytes of all 64 bytes
      EncryptPack.IV ivObj = EncryptPack.IV.fromUtf8(iv);
      EncryptPack.Key keyObj = EncryptPack.Key.fromUtf8(key);
      final encrypter = EncryptPack.Encrypter(
          EncryptPack.AES(keyObj, mode: EncryptPack.AESMode.cbc)); // Apply CBC mode
      String firstBase64Decoding = new String.fromCharCodes(
          ConvertPack.base64.decode(payload)); // First Base64 decoding
      final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(
          EncryptPack.Encrypted.fromBase64(firstBase64Decoding),
          iv: ivObj); // Second Base64 decoding (during decryption)
      return decrypted;
    }
```

Result is "Hello World" - correct

I tried to Encrypt in Dart the same string "Hello Word", but result is different

This is my wrong code, can you help me?

```
String enc(String payload) {
  String strPwd = "6P8yHVfeZ5JKaXQ6AyaBge";
  String strIv = 'cHaa5y7pQF5uqA2N';
  var iv = CryptoPack.sha256
      .convert(ConvertPack.utf8.encode(strIv))
      .toString()
      .substring(0, 16); // Consider the first 16 bytes of all 64 bytes
  var key = CryptoPack.sha256
      .convert(ConvertPack.utf8.encode(strPwd))
      .toString()
      .substring(0, 32); // Consider the first 32 bytes of all 64 bytes
  EncryptPack.IV ivObj = EncryptPack.IV.fromUtf8(iv);
  EncryptPack.Key keyObj = EncryptPack.Key.fromUtf8(key);

  final encrypter = EncryptPack.Encrypter(
      EncryptPack.AES(keyObj, mode: EncryptPack.AESMode.cbc));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(payload.toString(), iv: ivObj);

  return encrypted.base64; //try base16 too
}

String testdec = extractPayload("ZFNkckFEL2R5cW5ycTJpbWs0Ky9xQT09");
String testenc = enc(testdec);
print("ZFNkckFEL2R5cW5ycTJpbWs0Ky9xQT09   =>  " + testdec);
print(testdec + " => " + testenc);
```

base64 result:

```
I/flutter ( 7428): ZFNkckFEL2R5cW5ycTJpbWs0Ky9xQT09   =>  Hello World
I/flutter ( 7428): Hello World => dSdrAD/dyqnrq2imk4+/qA==
```

base16 result:

```
I/flutter ( 7428): ZFNkckFEL2R5cW5ycTJpbWs0Ky9xQT09   =>  Hello World
I/flutter ( 7428): Hello World => 75276b003fddcaa9ebab68a6938fbfa8
```

Comment: Without checking your code - the enc result looks like hex encoding and not base64 encoding

Comment: You're right, it's base16 example? I used 
return encrypted.base64 and it's not working too. (result = dSdrAD/dyqnrq2imk4+/qA==)

Comment: I edited original post, thank you @MichaelFehr

Comment: In the PHP code of the [referenced post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64933327/9014097), the ciphertext has been Base64 encoded/decoded _twice_. This is actually a bug in the PHP code, since double Base64 encoding/decoding does not give any advantage and unnecessarily increases the amount of data. Thus, to get the result you expect, you have to Base64 encode twice, e.g.: `return ConvertPack.base64.encode(ConvertPack.utf8.encode(encrypted.base64)); // Base64 encode twice // ZFNkckFEL2R5cW5ycTJpbWs0Ky9xQT09`.

Comment: It's working perfect. Thank you @Topaco